# Parsing Windows Batch File Parameters

Tags: batch-file

I have this for recognising a help parameter at the top of each of a set of batch files. Is there a briefer way, or is this as good as it gets?

```
@Echo Off
if "%1" == "" Goto Usage
if "%1" == "-?" Goto Usage
if "%1" == "/?" Goto Usage
if "%1" == "/help" Goto Usage
if "%1" == "-help" Goto Usage
if "%1" == "/Help" Goto Usage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it shorter:

```
if "%~1" == "" Goto Usage
if "%~1" == "-?" Goto Usage
if "%~1" == "/?" Goto Usage
if /i "%~1" == "/help" Goto Usage
if "%~1" == "-help" Goto Usage
```

`if /i` means ignore case. `"%~1"` to avoid double-double quotes.

You can ask for all useful answers and `goto usage` at the end:

```
if /i "%~1" == "a" Goto :doit_a
if /i "%~1" == "b" Goto :doit_b
if /i "%~1" == "c" Goto :doit_c
goto :Usage
```

Comment: at least the /i is a step forward on what I had, thanks. And your ~%1 is more accurate

Answer (score 2):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "help= -? /? -help /help "
if "%~1" equ "" goto Usage
if "!help: %~1 =!" neq "%help%" goto Usage
```

Comment: @JubjubBandersnatch I call this after its inventor "method Aacini" [please do not take too seriously:)] and you need `delayed expansion`.

Comment: @Endoro - I had seen this basic technique to check for a list of values posted on DosTips long before Aacini burst on the scene. I wouldn't be surprised if many people have come up with the idea independently. But it is an old concept.

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I asked please to not take it seriously.

Comment: Please, explain the magic?! The colon on line 4 is new to me and I don't get the trailing = inside the !! quotes.

Comment: Ah, got it: I should read line 4 as : expand the help variable, substituting %~1 with blank, and compare the result to the original. If the substitution caused difference, then %~1 was a substring of %help%.